# How to send email to multiple user and if the user has same ID then only send one email in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am trying to send and email to multiple users. These users can have the same ID sometimes. If the email is sent to this user, then instead sending 2 emails, only send one email to the users and move the next user to send the email.

```html
 $cusItems = DB::("Select * from items");
        //we will assume:
        //userid         email               item
        //   2             k@gmail.com        eggs
        //   4             m@yahoo.com         sugar
       //    2             k@gmail.com         milk


    foreach ($cusItems as $key) { 

      $uEmail = $key->email;
      $id = $key->userid;

        data = [
          'email' => $key->email,
          'item' => $key->item,
        ];

Mail::send(['html'=>'emailTemp'], $data , function($message) use ($uEmail, $id) { $message->to($uEmail, 'Your Items')->subject('Items #'. $id); $message->from('u2345245@deakincollege.com.au','Semester4'); }); }
```

then the email should be:-
when sent to user ID 2.

**First email template:-**

to: k@gmail.com
sub: XXX

Hi,

Your Items are :-

- eggs
- milk

thanks

**second email template:-**

to: m@yahoo.com
sub: XXX

Hi,

Your Items are :-

- sugar

thanks

Please let me know if I a not clear, my native language is not english and i have tried my best to explain. thanks

Comment: you are getting `$cusEmail` from `$cusItems` right?

Comment: yes, thats right

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the duplicates from the query it self so that you won't get any duplicate values.

your table:

```
 userid   email        item  itemid
    2   k@gmail.com    eggs     1
    4   m@yahoo.com    sugar    2
    2    k@gmail.com   milk     3
```

Change your query into

```
SELECT userid,email,GROUP_CONCAT(item) as items,GROUP_CONCAT(itemid) as itemids FROM `items`  GROUP BY userid
```

This will give you the following result. All you have to do is loop the query and send the mail with the items that are there for each user in one email.

```
userid   email         items     itemids
   2    k@gmail.com   eggs,milk   1,3
   4    m@yahoo.com   sugar        2
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: hi, i tried it and i am getting the results what u have shown here, thanks. But the Item ID is missing.

Comment: how did you get the itemId?  It's not stored in the DB yeah

Comment: well, this is a complex query. I tried to simplified and if possible when i am fetching the query at that time it emails the content.

Comment: do you have the item id stored in the db as well? And why do you need to have the item id since it is not there in the email template as well

Comment: yep, that in the same query. the data that goes in the template is not complete data. Just shows that it is created